# Test php file does not output to stdout from CLI on server (works locally)

Tags: php, stdout, php-ini

The question is *not* "HOW TO FIX THIS ERROR" but **"how do i get the output shown as well on the server, just as it does on my local install?"**

I run the php file like this

`php test.php`

Locally i get error and warning outputs. On a server operated by some devops, i get no output of the same file. I guess some php.ini value is set different? someone knows how to undo that?

In both cases the file execution fails.
this is the file

```
<?php ini_set('display_startup_errors',1);
ini_set('display_errors',1);
error_reporting(-1);
require(__DIR__ ."/../../../bootstrap.php");
?> TESTSTRING

<?php die("bye"); ?>
```

Now running this on the server I get NO output. Nothing.

Running it on my local computer i get:

```
Notice: Undefined index: HTTP_HOST in /var/www/html/myapp/wp-includes/ms-settings.php on line 38

Call Stack:
    0.0009     392912   1. {main}() /var/www/html/myapp/wp-content/themes/fundingpress-child/test.php:0
    0.0010     395888   2. require('/var/www/html/myapp/wp-content/themes/fundingpress-child/bootstrap.php') /var/www/html/myapp/wp-content/themes/fundingpress-child/test.php:6
    0.0065     687056   3. require_once('/var/www/html/myapp/wp-load.php') /var/www/html/myapp/wp-content/themes/fundingpress-child/bootstrap.php:7
    0.0066     699048   4. require_once('/var/www/html/myapp/wp-config.php') /var/www/html/myapp/wp-load.php:37
    0.0074     800592   5. require_once('/var/www/html/myapp/wp-settings.php') /var/www/html/myapp/wp-config.php:89
    0.0329    3665088   6. require('/var/www/html/myapp/wp-includes/ms-settings.php') /var/www/html/myapp/wp-settings.php:103


Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /var/www/html/myapp/wp-includes/ms-settings.php:38) in /var/www/html/myapp/wp-includes/ms-settings.php on line 187

Call Stack:
    0.0009     392912   1. {main}() /var/www/html/myapp/wp-content/themes/fundingpress-child/test.php:0
    0.0010     395888   2. require('/var/www/html/myapp/wp-content/themes/fundingpress-child/bootstrap.php') /var/www/html/myapp/wp-content/themes/fundingpress-child/test.php:6
    0.0065     687056   3. require_once('/var/www/html/myapp/wp-load.php') /var/www/html/myapp/wp-content/themes/fundingpress-child/bootstrap.php:7
    0.0066     699048   4. require_once('/var/www/html/myapp/wp-config.php') /var/www/html/myapp/wp-load.php:37
    0.0074     800592   5. require_once('/var/www/html/myapp/wp-settings.php') /var/www/html/myapp/wp-config.php:89
    0.0329    3665088   6. require('/var/www/html/myapp/wp-includes/ms-settings.php') /var/www/html/myapp/wp-settings.php:103
    0.0346    3804784   7. header() /var/www/html/myapp/wp-includes/ms-settings.php:187
```

Comment: Do you have access to change ini settings on the server?

Comment: i have root access yes

Comment: I think that error_reporting(-1) is not the recommended way to set it. May be this could be part of the problem.